# Repeating Words

Tags: word-choice

Is it necessary to put a comma before the conjunction `and`?

> "How many pages will we write and how long?"

I remember reading somewhere that no matter structure of a sentence when question words (sorry, not sure on the terminology here), or the like, repeat multiple times and have no subject in the part, you've to separate them with a comma.

*E.g.; how, how; when, when; then, then - and so on.*

Comment: Well in that particular example I certainly would put a comma. And my guess is that the more general answer to your question is going to be 'yes'. But to be certain about it I think you would need to give a few more examples of the sorts of sentences you envisage.

Comment: The example doesn't coordinate too well. _How many books did you buy and how much did they cost?_ doesn't need a comma, but some people would prefer one there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comma before *and*, *but*, *or*, or any of the other conjunctions **FANBOYS** is needed in two conditions
1. When we have three or more items in a series.

2.When "**FANBOYS**" is being used to coordinate two independent clauses.

In your case, I would say it's wrong to use a comma, because (*and how long*) is considered a dependent clause which is only could be understood by going to the independent clause (*how many pages will you write*).

Examples of using a comma before *and*

> [Miguel took piano lessons for sixteen years], and [today he is an accomplished performer].
>
> [The ice storm last week caused many tree limbs to fall on power lines], and [many people were without electricity for days].

Examples of not using a comma before *and*

> Miguel took piano lessons for sixteen years and today is an accomplished performer.
>
> The ice storm last week caused many tree limbs to fall on power lines and left many people without electricity for days.

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).